# method for validation of open and closed brackets

Tags: java, brackets

I'm Java beginner and I have to realize one or more methods for validation of open and closed brackets. For example: we have ()(()((()))) - it's true, or if we have ()) - false. It seems to me there is some simple solution of that, but I don't have any thoughts...
I do not ask you to write a solution (*well, if u want, I will not stop you* :D), but some hint would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Walk through the string and keep a counter of the currently opened, unclosed brackets. If you encounter '(', increment the counter, if you encounter ')', decrease the counter.
If the count is at any time less than 0, or is not 0 after you checked every char, then the string is not valid.

Just for fun a bit ugly and inefficient version:

```
System.out.println(s.chars().map((i) -> 81 - i * 2).reduce(0, (a, b) -> a >> 31 | a + b) == 0);
```

Comment: fyi this solution requires Java 8 or higher

Comment: Wow, nice idea. Thank you)